# php setlocales second parameter as string

Tags: php, localization

I'm trying to use php setlocale() for dates.
Setting it like:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pl_utf8','Polish','pl.UTF-8','Polish_Poland.1250','WINDOWS-1250');
```

works fine, but if I use variable which stores the second parameter like:

setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);

it does not work.

Now var $locale contains the exact string `'pl_utf8','Polish','pl.UTF-8','Polish_Poland.1250','WINDOWS-1250'`
which is being pulled from database.

Why isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$locale = "'foo','bar','baz'";
setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
```

is the same as

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "'foo','bar','baz'");
```

which is not the same as

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

The latter passes 4 separate arguments, the former two versions just pass 2 arguments, with the second argument not being in a format that `setlocale` understands. Alternatively to passing multiple strings, you can also pass an array:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'));
```

But to get the string `"'foo','bar','baz'"` into the form of the array `array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`, you have to do something like this:

```
$locales = array_map(function ($l) { return trim($l, "'"); }, explode(',', $locale));
```

Which is needlessly complicated. You need to store your locales differently in the database to simplify that, right now their format simply isn't suited well for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

Because  `$locale = 'pl_utf8','Polish','pl.UTF-8','Polish_Poland.1250','WINDOWS-1250';` is not valid PHP code (cause of the commas).

Like described in the official doc about [`setlocale()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) use an array for multiple values:

```
$locales = array('pl_utf8','Polish','pl.UTF-8','Polish_Poland.1250','WINDOWS-1250');
```

and call setlocale() with it.

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, $locales);
```